# template for loop couldn't handle array in ie11

Tags: javascript, templates, kendo-ui

We have a problem. We use a template for to add checkbox. But couldn't work on ie11. It's work on chrome,edge,firefox but couldn't work ie11.

```
  # for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { #
    # item = items[i]#
<input type="checkbox" #if(item.visible) {#checked#}# name="#:item.field#" data-bind="events:{ click: checkListener}" value="#:item.Field#"/>

<span>#: item.title #</span>
#}#
```

When I debug it, kendo was success. On back yard all data is available. But here doesn't work on just ie11. For loop seems work good, but item = items[i] doesn't work.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to debug for js errors in IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in Kendo-UI docs [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview), custom-variable declarations within templates should conform to following (usual to javascript, actually) pattern:

```
# var myCustomVariable = "foo"; #
<p>
    #= myCustomVariable #
</p>
```

It's most likely, that in `IE` custom variables with ommited `var identifier`/`trailing semicolon` are treated differently by kendo-ui templater, or there is an issue with scopes/attribute access for global-scoped variables in `compatibility mode` in `IE`.

Comment: no it doesn't matter, I tried that but we couldn't get any action. it work good on chrome or firefox or edge.

Comment: Maybe, `# for (var i = 0, item = items[i]; i < items.length; item = items[++i]) { #`, and delete that `# item = items[i]#` ?

Comment: or use `# var item = items[i]; #`

Comment: ahahahahah I solved like you said "var item = items[i]. thank you so much.

Comment: I turned your answer green tick. You should edit your answer as your command. If anybody get same problem on ie11, your answer will be visited first by he or she. thank you again.